# All records disappear in Mongodb/Ruby on Rails/Mongoid Model with hash field attribute and errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, hash, mongoid

I was wondering if any anyone else had a similar problem that I have seen - here's what happens;

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app using MongoDB and Mongoid
I have a model called Selectfield (like a select tag in a form) with an attribute called option_values that is a hash:

```
class Selectfield < Inputfield
    #inherits name and label from Inputfield

    field :option_values, type: Hash # key/vals for <option> in <select>
end
```

Long story short when I would save a new Selectfield sometimes I would get an error related to the option_values hash, and subsequently it would appear as if all the other records would have been lost. Going to inputfields controller, it would show no records even though I know I had 10+ records saved. This would persist after I fixed the error in the form.

What is odd is once I created a new Inputfield without errors, all the previously disappeared records would appear. I would think that this might be related to errors in the formatting of the hash, perhaps a misplaced quotation mark. Perhaps a poorly formatted hash caused the error and a new record would somehow resolve it?

While in the short term I have been able to resolve this problem, my biggest concern is how easy it is to corrupt MongoDB to make it appear that all records have been lost. Has anyone seen this problem? I've only been using MongoDB for a week, so I was wondering if this was an issue others had seen. I googled this type of error and did not see anyone with similar problems.

Also do I tell either Mongoid or MongoDB? Or do we chalk this up to user error?

Comment: This seems oddly specific to your application, and therefore I doubt anyone else would see it. If you can narrow it down to an example that we can easily reproduce on our machines then it would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is super-specific to the user's application.

Comment: While it may be app specific don't you think this is a catastrophic type error that others should be notified or made aware of? I don't think it is off topic at all.

Comment: No, I don't think it's a type error at all. I still think this is super specific to your application. Nothing except the code for a proof-of-concept application which proves that wrong would change my viewpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue - Selectfield and Textfield are classes that inherit from Inputfield, using single table inheritance. Selectfield and Textfield model classes would not get loaded until I tried to create one of them individually. Since I was running the application in DEV mode the default settings for the DEV environment does not cache the classes - there may be a better way to load the classes when the app starts but this setting change did the trick. I put it in the config/environements/development.rb file;

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

Hope this helps anyone who has this issue. Perhaps a standard ActiveRecord application will not have this problem, but I cannot say for certain.